# Laravel eloquent order by subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have a problem with ordering by columns in subquery (lastname, firstname).

I already tried this code as suggested by other posts:

```
->with(['customer' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy("lastname", "asc")
                ->orderBy("firstname", "asc");
        }])
```

Here my full code, but it doesn't work.

```
return Membership::forCompany($companyId)
        ->whereIn('state', ['ATTIVA', 'IN ATTESA DI ESITO', 'DA INVIARE'])
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                ->orWhereNull('end_date');
        })
        ->with('federation')
        ->with(['customer' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy("lastname", "asc")
                ->orderBy("firstname", "asc");
        }]);
```

Here the relationships:

In customer model I have:

```
public function memberships() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Membership');
}
```

In Membership model I have:

```
public function customer() {
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Customer");
}
```

Comment: You can't apply order on result's by it's subquery. It's totally wrong approach. Order by could be use with joins. If you would like to apply order by in the above situation... you should query from the customer table.

Comment: Thanks @VikashPathak but I need to order sometimes by lastname (customer table), sometimes by end_date (memebership table). How can I solve this labyrinth?

Comment: please share the relationships.

Comment: I added relationships on my original post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `orderBy()` with `join()` like:

```
$memberships = \DB::table("memberships")
                    ->where("company_id", $companyId)
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                            ->orWhereNull('end_date');
                    })
                    ->join("customers", "memberships.customer_id", "customers.id")
                    ->select("customers.*", "memberships.*")
                    ->orderBy("customers.lastname", "asc")
                    ->get();

dd($memberships);
```

Let me know if you are still having the issue. Note, code not tested! so you may need to verify by yourself once.

Comment: @Swim89 does this help?